# JQuery/Ajax: Render or Replace?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I attempting to make an ajax call using Jquery, but (using Firebug) discover that the ".render is not a function" in the following line of code:

```
$( '#readTemplate' ).render( response ).appendTo( "#records" );
```

So I downloaded jquery.render.js, which takes care of the render error, but I now get ".replace is not a function" on the following line(s):

```
 return tem.replace( /\$\{([^\}]+)\}\.each\(([^\)]+)\)/g, function( w, k, t )
```

I tried replaceTo, but that didn't work.  All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try assigning tem as a new var then use replace.

```
var newvar = tem;
newvar.replace( /\$\{([^\}]+)\}\.each\(([^\)]+)\)/g, function( w, k, t )
```

If that doesn't work try updating your version of jQuery.

Edit:

Make sure your var `tem` is a string as replace is a string function. So if:

```
var tem = "Some random string";
tem.replace()
```

replace would work. Make sure also that what ever is defining `tem` isn't returning null or undefined. Try alerting tem before the replace function and see what it returns.

Comment: Tried that, but no luck.  I'm using jquery 1.6.1.  The jquery.render.js files are using 1.4.4, but it doesn't make sense that 1.6.1. wouldn't be backwards compatible?  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the following with no luck: var bind = function( tem, o ){ var newvar = tem; alert(newvar); return newvar.replace( /\$\{([^\}]+)\}\.each\(([^\)]+)\)/g, function( w, k, t ){ That's only a snippet of the function but the first replace call. "tem" is an array of items passed in via JSON, so .replace will not work